Running a python application inside the Eclipse IDE with the PyDev plugin that requires a pyenv virtual environment
I am trying to execute the Eclipse IDE application with the PyDev plugin in order to develop an application written in Python (called SALT). When you execute the SALT application (outside of Eclipse) you first must activate a pyenv virtual environment using the command pyenv activate <virtual environment name>. I have asked in a separate stack overflow question whether there is a way to set the virtual environment in Eclipse before the SALT application executes. I have not received a response (it's been 4 days - Executing pyenv activate <virtualenv> before Eclipse with PyDev runs application), so I am looking for a way to use a shell script to set the virtual environment and then call Eclipse.
This approach is fraught with danger. Eclipse is written in Java and it is not evident that the Python application inherits the terminal session context from the Eclipse application. To know this would be to know how Eclipse implements running Python applications under its control (of which I have no knowledge). If Eclipse forks a process to run the Python application, it may well be that the pyenv virtual environment activation executed before running Eclipse has no effect on the Python execution (there is significant evidence of this, since when debugging SALT under Eclipse/PyDev, I get the following error dump:
0.01s - warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"/home/dan/dotpyenv/versions/3.10.15/bin/python3.10" "/home/dan/.var/app/org.eclipse.Java/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_12.2.0.202409031913/pysrc/setup_pydevd_cython.py" build_ext --inplace' to build.
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 191)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/dan/.var/app/org.eclipse.Java/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_12.2.0.202409031913/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 3699, in <module>
main()

... Trace back stuff ...

import distro
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distro'
[ERROR ] An un-handled exception was caught by Salt's global exception handler:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distro'

That the module 'distro' cannot be found suggests the virtual environment in which SALT runs is not set, even though the bash script first activates it before calling Eclipse. For the record, the script is:
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    echo "You must supply the name of an activation virtual environment"
    exit 1
fi

success=$(pyenv activate $1)

if [[ $success -ne 0 ]]
  then
    echo "The supplied virtual environment does not exist"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$2" ]
  then
    (/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=eclipse --file-forwarding org.eclipse.Java &)
else
    (/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=eclipse -data $2 --file-forwarding org.eclipse.Java &)
fi


I am really getting way over my head, especially because I have no understanding of flatpack and while Eclipse executes properly from this bash script (from the then clause of the if statement), I am not certain that the command in the else clause is properly written (especially, the -data $2 argument). Also, as specified above, running the debugger on the Python code generates the given error traceback.
Anyway, the reason I am posting this question is to ask for some help understanding how Eclipse and PyDev handle the interaction between virtual environments (specifically, those activated by pyenv) and the Python code managed in a workspace. Also, if there is a way to "attach" a virtual environment to a workspace or to a specific execution of the Python code encapsulated in a workspace, I would be very grateful if someone could point me to the documentation that discusses this.
